# How to make the viewport to be in the middle/center all the time? now it's on the left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

not sure how to do it and if I should do it by code or in the editor.

[image: view port more on the left]

I can drag the viewport on the red and put it more or less manual in the center. but I want it to be automatic in the center.

this screenshot is after dragging the red with the mouse:
and this is how I want it to be all the time.

[image: view port in the center]

this is a screenshot of the content object settings:

[image: content settings]

the problem is this script that sit on the HorizontalScrollView:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChiScrollRect : ScrollRect, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private static string mouseScrollWheelAxis = "Mouse ScrollWheel";
    private bool swallowMouseWheelScrolls = true;
    private bool isMouseOver = false;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isMouseOver = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isMouseOver = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Detect the mouse wheel and generate a scroll. This fixes the issue where Unity will prevent our ScrollRect
        // from receiving any mouse wheel messages if the mouse is over a raycast target (such as a button).
        if (isMouseOver && IsMouseWheelRolling())
        {
            var delta = UnityEngine.Input.GetAxis(mouseScrollWheelAxis);

            PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
            pointerData.scrollDelta = new Vector2(0f, delta);

            swallowMouseWheelScrolls = false;
            OnScroll(pointerData);
            swallowMouseWheelScrolls = true;
        }
    }

    public override void OnScroll(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (IsMouseWheelRolling() && swallowMouseWheelScrolls)
        {
            // Eat the scroll so that we don't get a double scroll when the mouse is over an image
        }
        else
        {
            // Amplify the mousewheel so that it matches the scroll sensitivity.
            if (data.scrollDelta.y < -Mathf.Epsilon)
                data.scrollDelta = new Vector2(0f, -scrollSensitivity);
            else if (data.scrollDelta.y > Mathf.Epsilon)
                data.scrollDelta = new Vector2(0f, scrollSensitivity);

            base.OnScroll(data);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsMouseWheelRolling()
    {
        return UnityEngine.Input.GetAxis(mouseScrollWheelAxis) != 0;
    }
}
```

I took that script from this answer:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/scroll-view-does-not-scroll-with-mousewheel-when-mouse-is-over-a-button-inside-the-scroll-view.848848/

the reason is because the problem: Scroll View does not scroll with MouseWheel when mouse is over a button inside the scroll view.

but this script also prevent from changing the Viewport to be in the center even if i'm changing the Anchor Presets of the Viewport to Middle/Center with holding down the alt and selecting the center square.

so I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Press the rect transform button, the one that looks like a target
[image: Unity rect transform]

Hold alt or shift or both, depending if you want to set the anchor, and scale to fill as well. Press the middle option (centre). This will allign your object to the centre of it's parent rect.

Comment: your solution should be the right one but I updated and edited my question and added a script and explained where is the problem and what cause it so it can't be center and why your solution is not working.